# Access file selected with paper-input

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to upload a file chosen through a Polymer `<paper-input type="file" id="filepicker">` element but when i try to access the file with:

```
var file = this.$.filepicker.files
```

i get a `files is not defined` error.

I haven't found any other methods to access files in paper inputs so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `files` property is found on the inner `<input>` element of `<paper-input>`, which you could access with [`<paper-input>.inputElement.inputElement`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-inputElement). So you would use this:

```
this.$.filepicker.inputElement.inputElement.files[0];
```

***Note**: In earlier versions of `<paper-input>`, the inner `<input>` was accessed with `this.$.filepicker.inputElement`, but it has since been refactored to have another container (hence, `this.$.filepicker.inputElement.inputElement`).*

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _handleFiles: function() {
      console.log(this.$.input.inputElement.inputElement.files[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.10.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-input type="file" id="input"></paper-input>
      <button on-tap="_handleFiles">Log file info</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/amQPkz?editors=1010)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot tony!

Comment: NB/ Polymer 2 does not seem to work like this, I get undefined with this code.

Comment: @IanWarner The `<paper-input>` was apparently refactored so the example stopped working, but I've fixed it. It also works in [Polymer 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zEmxRQ?editors=1010).